# How to solve Index 128 out of bounds for length 128 in elasticsearch exception

Tags: elasticsearch, exception, indexing, nested

`hello all getting error like this..

```
."caused_by" : {
"type" : "array_index_out_of_bounds_exception",
"reason" : "Index 128 out of bounds for length 128",
"caused_by" : {
"type" : "array_index_out_of_bounds_exception",
"reason" : "Index 128 out of bounds for length 128"
}
```

### Index out of bound in tophits[]aggregation

in the elasticsearch while doing top hits[] aggregation..on composite aggregation in nested fields.
picture of error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk2oI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk2oI.png)

Comment: Which version of the elasticsearch version you are using/

Comment: 7.9.1 @JinnaBalu

Comment: Instead of adding image for error codes, if you copy/paste that error then users can use them to answer your question more efficiently

Comment: ok @SubhashisPandey